# Return one of more parameters in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I have a function that inside have a if-else.My idea is to return a couple of parameters if the conditions is fulfilled or one string if the condition is not fulfilled . The problem is that in the function creation I put to returns more than one parameter.

```
function getOrigin (uint _id) isOwner public returns (address, string, uint32, uint16)
{
    if (travels[_id].clientAddress == msg.sender)
        return (travels[_id].clientAddress, travels[_id].originAirportName ,travels[_id].originTime ,travels[_id].originBagWeight);
    else 
        return (msg.sender,"Acceso prohibido",3,3);
}
```

At the moment I load fake values to the return. But if I want just to return the second parameter of the else return?

Comment: You can't. You cannot return a dynamic amount of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign dynamic variables to separate variables like this:

```
function getOrigin (uint _id) isOwner public returns (address, string, uint32, uint16)
{
    if (travels[_id].clientAddress == msg.sender) {
        address a = travels[_id].clientAddress;
        string memory b = travels[_id].originAirportName;
        uint32 c = travels[_id].originTime;
        uint16 d = travels[_id].originBagWeight;
        return (a, b, c, d);
    }
    else 
        return (msg.sender,"Acceso prohibido",3,3);
}
```

Note: Only assigning `b` variable is necessary. Others are for butifying the code.

Comment: why you use memory for just the b value?

Comment: because default is storage and here no need to storage.

Comment: oquei thx. But just one question why i have to recover the values into variables?? It´s not better to return directly from the struct that i have data no (travels[_id].clientAddress)??? cheaper gas cost??

Comment: This is because your defined struct is meaningful only interior of your contract not out of it. So if you define your contract as `internal`, you can use a struct as the return parameter.